# S-attributed grammar may specify AST?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar

As far as I understand, using return values and element labels in [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) are sufficient to build an AST. e.g.

```
r returns [int c, String d] :   
        a='class' b=ID  ... {$c=$b; $d=$a;}
```

Is this kind of extension to [eBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) called a [S-attributed grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-attributed_grammar)?

Is it common to build ASTs that way?

I'm especially interested in [unparsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unparsing) an AST (**not** a parse tree) build from this attributed grammar. Are there any benefits from restricting the attributes to pure assignments? (no function calls e.g. `$c= fun($a)` ) I've explained my unparsing problem [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918961/unparse-ast-oexpn).

Comment: S-attributed grammar simply means a grammar that only uses attributes whose values come from children of nonterminals. So if you have S: A; as a grammar A could pass an attribute(value) to S but S could not pass an attribute to A.